# Receive error when I run an executable created after py2exe conversion

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, py2exe

After running my setup.py file and attempt to run the newly created .exe file I receive an error log that says:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Healthy_temp.py", line 7, in <module>
    File "pandas\__init__.pyc", line 42, in <module>
    File "pandas\core\api.pyc", line 26, in <module>
    File "pandas\core\groupby\__init__.pyc", line 1, in <module>
    File "pandas\core\groupby\groupby.pyc", line 37, in <module>
    File "pandas\core\frame.pyc", line 100, in <module>
    File "pandas\core\series.pyc", line 4390, in <module>
    File "pandas\core\generic.pyc", line 10138, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    File "pandas\core\window.pyc", line 14, in <module>
    File "pandas\_libs\window.pyc", line 12, in <module>
    File "pandas\_libs\window.pyc", line 10, in __load
    File "pandas\_libs\skiplist.pxd", line 31, in initpandas._libs.window
    ImportError: No module named skiplist
```

My setup.py file is here:

```
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe
    import matplotlib
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    from AboutDialog import Ui_Dialog
    from matplotlibwidget import MatplotlibWidget
    import sys
    from os import walk
    from os import getcwd
    import pandas
    import numpy
    from glob import glob
    from datetime import datetime
    from math import isnan
    import sip

    # setup(windows=['Healthy_temp.py'])
    setup(options={'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 3, 'compressed': True}}, windows=[
          'Healthy_temp.py'], zipfile=None,
          data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())
```

What can I do to correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add 'pandas._libs.skiplist' to the "includes" option list.